# Knockout Array buttons one Function

Tags: javascript, html, button, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

I've started learning Knockout and I'm having some trouble. I've observable Array, which have some buttons. I need:
Example:

- I click first button 'lock' and visible first span 'lock', hide first span 'unlock'. And this should be one function 'lock'.
- I click first button 'unlock' and hide first span 'lock', visible first span 'unlock'. And this should be one function 'unlock'.
- I click second button 'lock' and visible second span 'lock', hide second span 'unlock'. And this should be one function 'lock'.
- etc.

I don't know... How to do it ?

Help, please!

This is my model:

```
function newNames() {
    var self = this;

    self.btnClick = ko.observable(true);

    self.newName = ko.observable();

    self.names = ko.observableArray([
        {id: 1, name: 'Name1'},
        {id: 2, name: 'Name2'},
        {id: 3, name: 'Name3'}
    ]);

    self.lock = function () {
        self.btnClick(false);
    };

    self.unlock = function () {
        self.btnClick(true);
    };

    self.clickRename = function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.names().length; i++) {
            if (self.btnClick() == false) {
            } else {
                self.names.replace(self.names()[i], {
                    name: self.newName()
                });
            }
        }
    };
};
ko.applyBindings(new newNames());
```

This is the html:

```
<div class="form-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: newName">

<button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: clickRename">
    RENAME
</button>

</div>


<div class="group" data-bind="foreach: names">

    <div class="form">
        <!-- hidden: $parent.btnClick() == false, visible: $parent.btnClick() == true
        $parent.btnClick() == false -->

        <span id="span1" data-bind="visible: $parent.btnClick">unlock</span>
        <span id="span2" data-bind="hidden: $parent.btnClick() == true, visible: $parent.btnClick() == false">lock</span>


<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name">

<button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.lock">
    LOCK
</button>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: $root.unlock">
    UNLOCK
</button>

        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this.
Anyway you can improve the code adding a computed property on object array with label for the button.

I have passed a value to the click of button where setup the corresponding new property **lock** and consequently show/hide the corresponding span.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: newName">
            <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: clickRename">    RENAME   </button>
        </div>


        <div class="group" data-bind="foreach: names">

            <div class="form">
                <span id="span1" data-bind="visible: lock() == true">unlock</span>
                <span id="span2" data-bind="visible: lock() == false">lock</span>


                <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: name">

                <button type="button" class="btn" data-bind="click: function(data, event) { $parent.lock(!lock(), data, event); }">
                    <span data-bind="visible: lock() == false">LOCK</span>
                    <span data-bind="visible: lock() == true">UN-LOCK</span>

                </button>


            </div>
        </div>
        <script>




            function newNames() {
                var self = this;

                self.btnClick = ko.observable(true);

                self.newName = ko.observable();

                self.names = ko.observableArray([
                     { id: 1, name: 'Name1', lock: ko.observable(false) },
                     { id: 2, name: 'Name2', lock: ko.observable(false) },
                     { id: 3, name: 'Name3', lock: ko.observable(false) }
                 ]);

                self.lock = function (value, data, event) {
                    console.log(data);
                    data.lock(value);
                };

                self.clickRename = function () {
                    for (var i = 0; i < self.names().length; i++) {
                        if (self.btnClick() == false) {
                        } else {
                            self.names.replace(self.names()[i], {
                                name: self.newName()
                            });
                        }
                    }
                };
            };
            ko.applyBindings(new newNames());
        </script>
```

Comment: Ok. It's great! But how can I make RENAME button?

Comment: Example: 
- if first 'lock' -> don't rename input and don't rename in the array 'Name1'.
- if second 'unlock' -> do rename input and do rename in the array 'Name2'. 
- etc.
Data from input div class="form-group"...

Thank you for your previous answer!

Comment: Is not clear, explain better what do you want to achieve, update your question with example

Comment: Thank you very much, Max! I understand and did it! You are cool!